# Configure Port for Plugin Debugger, Android studio

Tags: android, ddms, android-device-monitor

I am trying to configure my port for the Debug in Android Studio 3.2.3. I am using the Smalidea Plugin to Debugge. According to this Guide I should see what is the port of my plugin in the "Android Device Monitor" but my version of Android Studio does not work anymore. Any ideas? Thank you

Guide that followed: https://crosp.net/blog/software-development/mobile/android/android-reverse-engineering-debugging-smali-using-smalidea/

[Print Screen, Port to setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/662qC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Run -> Attach Debugger to Android Process` instead of a "Remote debug configuration". You should see the process of your app if it is debuggable (add attribute `android:debuggable="true"` to tag `application` in `AndroidManifest.xml`) and running. Ensure that you have enabled debugging of the app on your device: `Developer options -> Select debug app` and (optionally) enable
`Wait for debugger`.